# Dealing with multiple keyboard layouts (OSX vs. Windows)

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, keyboard-layout

I have two computers; one MacBook Pro and one desktop PC running Windows. For various reasons I prefer writing code on the MacBook, while I keep the desktop PC mostly for gaming and entertainment purposes.

Since I've gotten so used to programming on an OSX keyboard layout, I often find it cumbersome to start working on something while I'm on my Windows computer. And since I'm ridiculously lazy I also find it cumbersome to get my laptop out of my bag so I can switch to using that instead. This usually results in me not bothering to do much work while I'm on my desktop (which depressingly enough is most of my evenings).

I guess I'm looking for a way to quickly enable an OSX keyboard layout in Windows. I'd also like to run Ubuntu in a VM on Windows, and use the OSX keyboard there as well.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), using your Mac keyboard on both the PC and Mac.

Comment: Although, a QWERTY keyboard is a QWERTY keyboard is a QWERTY keyboard... Unless its mechanical.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it out and report back. However, a QWERTY keyboard is only a QWERTY keyboard if they're both standard English edition. With say, a Norwegian keyboard they might be very different indeed.

Comment: @Orolin I know in Windows you can create shortcut keys to switch from one keyboard layout to another, but you can also switch keyboard types too, so if you're comfortable using a Mac keyboard, I'd recommend just changing your keyboard type to your Mac layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to create a custom keyboard layout on Windows that mirrors the Mac OS one.

Ubuntu has an infinitely flexible and impossibly complicated keyboard layout system called XKB, which has [limited](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/index.html) [documentation](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/PDF/). Ubuntu probably already has all the data for the Mac keyboard layout you want stored among the hundreds of files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, but figuring out how to load it will drive you crazy. You might have luck asking about this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or the [Unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).